# Problem differentiating between [Char] and [[Char]] in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

So I have this function that is supposed to return a string (or [Char]). Here is a very bare-boned version of it:

```
test :: Int -> Int -> [Char]
test n1 n2 = do
    if n1 >= n2 then return "return 1"
    else do
        (...)
        return "return 2"
```

Now to my understanding, "return 1" and "return 2" are strings. They should have the type [Char]. But for some reason, when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
Cards.hs:284:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In the expression: return "return 1"
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if n1 >= n2 then return "return 1" else do return "return 2"
      In the expression:
        do if n1 >= n2 then return "return 1" else do return "return 2"
    |
284 |     if n1 >= n2 then return "return 1"
```

Can anyone tell me while the program recognizes these strings as [[Char]]? Because I have also tried to concatenate the return value before returning, and when I did that, it recognized it as type [Char].

Comment: short answer: don't use `do` and `return` unless you know you need them

Comment: THis is due to the `return`, this means you wrap items in a monadic context, and here that context is a list, so that means you create a singleton list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem May I know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Basically `if n1 > n2 then "return 1" else "return 2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me while the program recognizes these strings as `[[Char]]`?

You are working with a `do` block. This means you are working with monads. A list is a monad. [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) wraps items in a monadic context. For a list that thus means that the value you "return" is wrapped in a singleton list.

I would advise *not* to work with `do` and `return` until you learn about monads, especially since `return` has not the same semantics as in an imperative language like Python or Java for example.

You can here work with guards and implement this as:

```
test :: Int -> Int -> [Char]
test n1 n2
    | n1 >= n2 = "return 1"
    | otherwise = "return 2"
```

Comment: And can I use a do after the "otherwise"? Because the real function is a lot more complicated and needs to do a lot of other thing then just returning a string.

Comment: @bobthesnob: no. If you need to work with I/O then you will need an `IO [Char]`, if the `otherwise` simply means more conditions you can add extra guards. You can also work with helper functions to simplify the implementation. Usualy functions in Haskell only consists of a few lines.